# Why is the iPhone 5 magnetic on the back near the camera lens?

Tags: iphone

The iPhone 5 magnetic enough on the back near the camera lens to attach a staple to. Why there is a magnet there and what it is for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very likely to be the speaker. Because yes, speaker use magnets.

It's on opposite side of the top speaker only and looking at [this picture](http://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/DIsaXjsiLvlOTMRx.huge) (courtesy of [iFixit's iPhone teardown](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPhone+5+Teardown/10525)) there is nothing else that is magnetic.